# Swift UISearchController when select item search bar is still there

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have two problems with `UISearchController`.
I use this setup for UISearchController:

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Traži.."
    resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Učitaj podatke..")
    refreshControl!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1, green:0.48, blue:0, alpha:0.3)
    refreshControl!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ArticleTableViewController.getArticleData), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)
}
```

**First problem**

when i click on search bar textfield, `UIRefreshControl` shows but it shouldn't:

[image]

**Second problem**

when i search for item, and click on it, i use Storyboard segue to open that item in new viewcontroller, but problem is that search bar is still there on that new VC(first image is searching, second image shows new VC opened):

[image]
[image]

Comment: you have to cleare the searchbar textfield befor moving to next screen

Comment: - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
}

Comment: But this is not cancel button that i am clicking

Comment: put this code befor you move to next screen searchBar.text = @"";

Comment: That doesn't hide searchbar..

Comment: you have use same vc for both data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Traži.."
    resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Učitaj podatke..")
    refreshControl!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1, green:0.48, blue:0, alpha:0.3)
    refreshControl!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ArticleTableViewController.getArticleData), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)


    // this hide search bar on next VC, first problem 
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    // second problem
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(resultSearchController.searchBar.frame));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use a UISearchBar instead of the UISearchController? Try this code:

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 40
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let newViewController = UIViewController()
    newViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    newViewController.title = "\(indexPath.row)"
    navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}


func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    NSLog(searchText)
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="u8Q-4a-0UD">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_38971807" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <searchBar contentMode="redraw" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GdH-fg-5TJ">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="600" height="44"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </searchBar>
                        <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tP2-Xq-aem">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="108" width="600" height="492"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <prototypes>
                                <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="cell" textLabel="RcZ-LI-9Ir" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleDefault" id="13y-5Y-dcw">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="600" height="44"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="13y-5Y-dcw" id="ldM-4e-kie">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="43"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Title" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="RcZ-LI-9Ir">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="15" y="0.0" width="570" height="43"/>
                                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                                                <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </tableViewCellContentView>
                                </tableViewCell>
                            </prototypes>
                        </tableView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="GdH-fg-5TJ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="Fwk-Jx-EJc"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="GdH-fg-5TJ" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Q3j-AV-Tnj"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="tP2-Xq-aem" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="T9u-C9-1HD"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="GdH-fg-5TJ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="Y9o-yO-w6R"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="GdH-fg-5TJ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="tP2-Xq-aem" secondAttribute="leading" id="l4X-RD-XEW"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="GdH-fg-5TJ" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="tP2-Xq-aem" secondAttribute="trailing" id="pcF-ST-Zkq"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="tP2-Xq-aem" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="GdH-fg-5TJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="ze4-D7-NeF"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="pJE-Q4-d47"/>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="searchBar" destination="GdH-fg-5TJ" id="N81-72-8HH"/>
                    <outlet property="tableView" destination="tP2-Xq-aem" id="lYV-er-UNj"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1075" y="-133"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Navigation Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="Q5J-kb-qjE">
        <objects>
            <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="u8Q-4a-0UD" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <toolbarItems/>
                <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ey2-Nm-1yZ">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </navigationBar>
                <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="A3N-1a-Rlv"/>
                </connections>
            </navigationController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="QFX-N3-4dT" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="218" y="-133"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: And when i go back, do i need to show that searchbar again?

Comment: Yes. Also in tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) you can set UISearchController  to your new viewController ("vc" in code above). And then you should  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {resultSearchController.searchBar.hidden = false} of your vc.

Comment: But when i use `viewDidApear` and set `hidden` to `false`, it is slow, and search doesn't filter?

Comment: Try viewWillDissapear in child vc, not viewDidAppear.